# CharJs scrolling page on mobile

Tags: vue.js, mobile, chart.js

We have an application in VueJs, in the home page everything works fine.
When we load the page on mobile, we have few problems on scrolling, if we touch the chart and try to scroll the page down, the touch it's like intercepted from the chart and make the scoll impossible.
So in order to scroll the page we have to start scrolling from outside the chart.

I tried to add in the chart options the following `events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click',],` thinking that like so it would exclude the touch options, but it dosen't work as well.

I've also tried with the following but no success.

```
tooltips: {
    enabled: false
},
 events: [],
```

Any suggestion? Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few hours I've found a solution.
Seems like that in the canvas of the chart there is a css propriety `touch-action: none;` setting that one to `touch-action: unset` solved my problem.

```
<template>
  <canvas class="chart-mobile" ref="canvas"/>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .chart-mobile {
    touch-action: unset !important;
  }
</style>
```